# st_transform on planet_osm_line to get lat and lon coordinates - extra data returned

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap

I'm using this query to get all the lat and lon coordinates on a way from planet_osm_line:

```
select st_astext(st_transform(way, 4326))
from planet_osm_line 
where osm_id = 482283890;
```

The result is:
LINESTRING(11.6168586 46.5434487002502,11.6168345 46.5431350002503,11.6167899 46.5429099002503,11.6172158 46.5425886002504,11.6176661 46.5424470002504,11.6180585 46.5424763002504,11.6181788 46.5425033002504,11.618848 46.5427728002503,11.6193672 46.5429585002503,11.6204657 46.5429528002503,11.6214048 46.5432146002503,11.6222983 46.5436187002502,11.6224615 46.5436944002502)

What I see are the lon and lat coordinates for every node constructing the line, but the lat seems to contain extra information (last 6 digits, ie 002502).
What is this information and how can I seperate it from the lat coordinate?

Comment: the solution is shown here - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204418/force-coordinate-precision-in-qgis-when-saving-feature-to-postgis

Comment: Looks like this solution applies to the precision of the geometry way and not on the precision of lon and lat as a result from st_astext(st_transform(..)). Not the precision of lat appears to be much higher making me assume some extra information

Comment: There is no need to believe that the last digits in a decimal number carry any extra  information. They are just last digits in a decimal number.

Comment: You are very right, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSM [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) coordinates have 7 decimals. PostGIS stores geometries with 15 decimals. The difference between the two is noise and should not be relied on. In fact, you should instruct `st_asText` to show only 7 digits.

```sql
select st_astext(st_transform(way, 4326),7)
from planet_osm_line 
where osm_id = 482283890;
```

There is an interesting note in the doc, hidden the [`ST_QuantizeCoordinates`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_QuantizeCoordinates.html) function, which is used to consistently set the unused bits to 0

> PostGIS stores all coordinate values as double-precision floating
>   point integers, which can reliably represent 15 significant digits.
>   However, PostGIS may be used to manage data that intrinsically has
>   fewer than 15 significant digits. An example is TIGER data, which is
>   provided as geographic coordinates with six digits of precision after
>   the decimal point (thus requiring only nine significant digits of
>   longitude and eight significant digits of latitude.)
>
> When 15 significant digits are available, there are many possible
>   representations of a number with 9 significant digits. A double
>   precision floating point number uses 52 explicit bits to represent the
>   significand (mantissa) of the coordinate. Only 30 bits are needed to
>   represent a mantissa with 9 significant digits, leaving 22
>   insignificant bits; we can set their value to anything we like and
>   still end up with a number that rounds to our input value. For
>   example, the value 100.123456 can be represented by the floating point
>   numbers closest to 100.123456000000, 100.123456000001, and
>   100.123456432199. All are equally valid, in that ST_AsText(geom, 6) will return the same result with any of these inputs.

Comment: All clear now, a precision issue it is. Thanks a lot!